# How to make these button runs differently?

Tags: javascript, php

Well i have generate buttons. Their function are the same which is when i clicked it , it will do the calculations. the problem is when i clicked the  second generate button, it will do the calculations for the first one and same goes to third button and so on. what i want is, each generate button will only do calculation for their own job. Can anyone help me ?

[my generate button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkW1v.png)

And below is the code :

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td style="font-family:centruy-gothic"<strong><font color = "black">
    <?echo $listb['task_name'];?>
    <input type="hidden" name="pc_id[]" value="<? echo $pc_id;?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="ps_id[]" value="<? echo $ps_id;?>" >
    </font></strong></td>
    <td align="center" style="font-family:century gothic"><input type="text" id ="task_mark" class="input-medium" name="task_mark[]" value="<? echo $listb['task_mark'];?>" onchange="getDate()"/></td>
    <td align="center" style="font-family:century gothic"><input type="text" id="marking" class="input-medium" name="marking[]" value="<? echo $listb['marking'];?>"onchange="getDate()"/></td>
    <td align="center" style="font-family:century gothic"><input type="text" id="destination_marking" class="input-medium" name="destination_marking[]" value="<? echo $listb['destination_marking'];?>"onchange="getDate()"/></td>
    <td align="center" style="font-family:century gothic"><input type="text" id="days" class="input-medium" name="days[]" value="<? echo $listb['days'];?>"onchange="getDate()"/></td>
    <td align="center" style="font-family:century gothic"><input type="text" id="duration" class="input-medium" name="duration[]" value="<? echo $listb['duration'];?>" onchange="calc()"/></td>
    <td align="center" style="font-family:century gothic"><input type="text" id="start_date" class="input-long" name="start_date[]" value="<? echo $listb['start_date'];?>" class="date demo" onchange="getDate()" ></td>
    <td align="center" style="font-family:century gothic"><input type="text" id="end_date" class="input-long" name="end_date[]" value="<? echo $listb['end_date'];?>" class="date demo" onchange="getDate()"></td>
    <td align="center" ><input class="submit-green" id="end_date" type="button" name="end_date[]" value="GENERATE" onclick="getDate()"></td>

    </tr>
```

And here's the script

```
<script>
        function getDate()

    {   

        var sd = document.getElementById('start_date').value;
        var dura = document.getElementById('duration').value;
        var m = document.getElementById('marking').value;

        var date = new Date(sd);
        var newdate = new Date (date);
        var durations = parseInt(dura);
        var markings = parseInt(m);

        if (markings === 1)
        {
            newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate());
        }
        else if (markings === 2)
        {
            newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + durations);
        }
        else if (markings === 3)
        {
            newdate.setDate((newdate.getDate() + durations) + 1 );
        }

        var dd = newdate.getDate();
        var mm = newdate.getMonth()+1;
        var y = newdate.getFullYear();

        var someFormattedDate = y + '-' + mm +'-' + dd;
        document.getElementById('end_date').value = someFormattedDate;

    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Well, try to give a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for example. That way we can see the comportement of your script and you can answer.

Comment: this is not a mysql related question maybe someone can remove the mysql tag?

Comment: sorry this is mysql related ..because the data i get is from mysql .. do you also need my mysql code also ?

Comment: This is not a mysql question because it doesn't matter where you get your info from. You don't have a problem with your sql code, you have a problem with your javascript or php code even if you get the data from mysql or from the user input.

Comment: noted it @nacho

Comment: got it ! thank you guys ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can give a parameter in the html code modifying the `onchange="getDate()"` like this:

```
<td align="center" style="font-family:century gothic"><input type="text" id ="task_mark" class="input-medium" name="task_mark[]" value="<? echo $listb['task_mark'];?>" onchange="getDate(1)"/></td>
<td align="center" style="font-family:century gothic"><input type="text" id="marking" class="input-medium" name="marking[]" value="<? echo $listb['marking'];?>"onchange="getDate(2)"/></td>
<td align="center" style="font-family:century gothic"><input type="text" id="destination_marking" class="input-medium" name="destination_marking[]" value="<? echo $listb['destination_marking'];?>"onchange="getDate(3)"/></td>
<td align="center" style="font-family:century gothic"><input type="text" id="days" class="input-medium" name="days[]" value="<? echo $listb['days'];?>"onchange="getDate(4)"/></td>
<td align="center" style="font-family:century gothic"><input type="text" id="duration" class="input-medium" name="duration[]" value="<? echo $listb['duration'];?>" onchange="calc()"/></td>
<td align="center" style="font-family:century gothic"><input type="text" id="start_date" class="input-long" name="start_date[]" value="<? echo $listb['start_date'];?>" class="date demo" onchange="getDate(5)" ></td>
<td align="center" style="font-family:century gothic"><input type="text" id="end_date" class="input-long" name="end_date[]" value="<? echo $listb['end_date'];?>" class="date demo" onchange="getDate(6)"></td>
<td align="center" ><input class="submit-green" id="end_date" type="button" name="end_date[]" value="GENERATE" onclick="getDate(7)"></td>
```

Then, in the script you get the parameter to do different things:

```
<script>
        function getDate(param)
    {
```

And now you now wich of the button he checked

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a `foreach` before your table rows.
In this case u have several times the same id for each input field.

Try to make the id's unique. Something like this:

```
<input type="text" id ="task_mark_row1">
```

//next table row:

```
<input type="text" id ="task_mark_row2">
```

...